Issue with Passing Variables Between UserForm and Main Code in Outlook VBA
I would classify myself as a "copy-paste programmer"—I know enough to be dangerous, and I often rely on tools like ChatGPT to help write my code. However, I frequently get stuck when it comes to passing variables back and forth between procedures because I don’t fully understand the underlying mechanics.
Currently, I’m struggling with a cancel button issue in a VBA UserForm. The problem lies in passing the value of a variable (CancelSend) from a button click event back to the main code. Here’s what’s happening:
When I click the cancel button, the CancelSend variable updates correctly within the CommandButton7_Click sub.
However, when control returns to the main code, it’s like the variable never changed.
I even tested this with a simple string variable:
I set the string to a value before calling the UserForm.
In the CommandButton7_Click sub, I changed the string's value.
Despite this, when I check the string in the main code after the UserForm is closed, it retains its original value.
Interestingly, if I add MsgBox statements in the CommandButton7_Click sub to check the values, they do reflect the changes there. But those changes are not reflected in the main code once the UserForm is closed.
The bottom line is:
The CancelSend variable is not making its way back to the main code as True, so the email is sent immediately when it shouldn’t be.
Here’s the relevant portion of my code for reference:
Dim obj, myEmail As Object
Dim Mail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim WkDay, MinNow, SendHour, UserDeferOption As Integer
Dim SendNow, Des As String

Option Explicit
Private objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Public WithEvents objCalendar As Outlook.Folder
Public WithEvents objCalendarItems As Outlook.Items
Public SendDate As Date
Public CancelSend As Boolean

Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' Declare variables
    'Dim SendDate As Date
    Dim SendHour As Integer
    Dim MinNow As Integer
    Dim WkDay As Integer
    Dim obj As Object
    Dim Mail As Outlook.MailItem

    SendDate = Now()
    SendHour = Hour(Now)
    MinNow = Minute(Now)
    WkDay = Weekday(Now)

    ' Check sending time and adjust SendDate as needed
    If SendHour < 7 Then
        SendDate = DateAdd("h", 8 - SendHour, SendDate)
        SendDate = DateAdd("n", -MinNow, SendDate)
    ElseIf SendHour >= 19 Or (WkDay = vbSaturday Or WkDay = vbSunday) Then
        Dim HoursToAdd As Integer

        If WkDay = vbSaturday Then
            HoursToAdd = 32 - SendHour ' Next Monday at 8 AM
        ElseIf WkDay = vbFriday And SendHour >= 19 Then
            HoursToAdd = 57 - SendHour ' Next Monday at 8 AM
        Else
            HoursToAdd = 32 - SendHour ' Next day at 8 AM
        End If

        SendDate = DateAdd("h", HoursToAdd, SendDate)
        SendDate = DateAdd("n", -MinNow, SendDate)
    End If

    ' Get the active message
    Set obj = getActiveMessage()

    If obj Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' Handle null case

    If TypeOf obj Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        Set Mail = obj

        ' Open the user form to handle delay selection
        Call ShowDelayUserForm(Mail)
    End If

    ' Set the deferred delivery time if SendDate is set
    If SendDate > Now Then
        Mail.DeferredDeliveryTime = SendDate ' Set the deferred delivery time
    End If
    
    
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' Check if CancelSend is set to True
    If CancelSend = True Then
        Cancel = True  ' Prevent the email from being sent
        CancelSend = False  ' Reset CancelSend to False for next time
        Exit Sub
    End If
    

    ' Additional logic for handling recipients
    Dim Recipients As Recipients
    Dim Recipient As Recipient

    If item.Class = olMail Then
        Set Recipients = item.Recipients
        For Each Recipient In Recipients
            Recipient.Resolve
            If Not Recipient.Resolved Then
                MsgBox "The email address for '" & Recipient.Address & "' could not be resolved. Please check the recipient's email address.", vbExclamation, "Address Resolution Failed"
                Cancel = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Recipient
        Set Recipients = Nothing
    End If

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error"
    Cancel = True
End Sub

Private Sub ShowDelayUserForm(Mail As Outlook.MailItem)
    ' Display the user form and retrieve the selected delay
    TimeSelection.Show vbModal ' Open the form in modal mode

    ' Check if the user selected a delay value
    If TimeSelection.SelectedSendDate <> 0 Then
        ' Use the selected send date and time
        SendDate = TimeSelection.SelectedSendDate
    ElseIf TimeSelection.SelectedDelayMinutes > 0 Then
        ' Use the selected delay in minutes
        SendDate = DateAdd("n", TimeSelection.SelectedDelayMinutes, Now())
    End If

    ' Unload the form after use
    Unload TimeSelection
    
End Sub

Function getActiveMessage() As Outlook.MailItem
Dim insp As Outlook.Inspector
If TypeOf Application.ActiveWindow Is Outlook.Inspector Then
        Set insp = Application.ActiveWindow
    End If
If insp Is Nothing Then
        Dim inline As Object
        Set inline = Application.ActiveExplorer.ActiveInlineResponse
        If inline Is Nothing Then Exit Function
Set getActiveMessage = inline
    Else
       Set insp = Application.ActiveInspector
       If insp.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then
          Set getActiveMessage = insp.CurrentItem
       Else
         Exit Function
       End If
End If
End Function



Private Sub CommandButton7_Click()
    ' Set CancelSend to True to prevent the email from being sent
    CancelSend = True
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Any guidance on how to properly pass variables from a UserForm to the main code would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Why are you using getActiveMessage when the mail item in question is passed directly to Application_ItemSend as item?   Would help to edit your code listing and separate out the code which is in the userform from the rest of the code.
